# How to fix asynchronous execution of .subscribe and bind data together?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to call an API which gives me 2 values: a link and an id.
It looks like this example:

```
{'link' : ['link1','link2'], 'id' : ['id1','id2']}
```

Every link is an API so I call them again in a for loop and after that,  I retrieve my data which is of type Movie, add it to movies and send it using a callback.

The problem is that id's don't bind correctly to the links because I use .subscribe and I end up with id1 assigned to link2 sometimes.

This is the code:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.searchForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    //call first API
    this.movieService.getMovieLink(this.f.search.value) 
        .subscribe(response => {
          this.idStr = response['link']  // string of links
          this.myIdS = response['id']   // string of id's

          for (let index in this.idStr) {
            this.myId = this.myIdS[index] 
            this.movieService.id = this.idStr[index]; 
            //call API I got from links
            this.movieService.getMovie2()  
                  .subscribe( response => {

                        this.movies.push({
                        // this does not correspond to the actual id
                        id : this.myId,  
                        name : response['Title'],
                        releaseDate : response['Released'],
                        genres : response['Genre'],
                        description : response['Plot'],
                        starRating : response['imdbRating'],
                        imageUrl : response['Poster']
                      })  
                      //send data from .subscribe with a function
                      if (Number(index) == this.idStr.length - 1) {
                             this.mycallback(this.movies)
                      }

                    },
                    err => {console.error(err)
                 })  
          }    
          this.movies = [];
})
}
```

My question is How can I bind the links with the id's so values inside movie will correspond?

Comment: The question is asking for logic of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mergeMap/flatMap instead of multiple subscriptions.

```
this.movieService.getMovieLink(this.f.search.value) 
        .mergeMap(response => {
          let links = response['link']  // array of links
          let ids = response['id']   // array of ids

          return ids.map( (myId,index) => {
            let link = links[index];  // <-- where is this used ?
            return this.movieService.getMovie2() // <-- probably pass link here instead of depending on side-effect by setting movieService.id 
                  .map( res =>   
                        ({
                        id : myId,  
                        name : response['Title'],
                        releaseDate : response['Released'],
                        genres : response['Genre'],
                        description : response['Plot'],
                        starRating : response['imdbRating'],
                        imageUrl : response['Poster']
                        })
                     )
                 })  
          })
}).subscribe(val => //should give you the array you are expecting...
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.myId = this.myIdS[index]` reassign the myId property of the class every time the API response, therefore the value of this.myId is not reliable. For example, you create a request A, and then request B, but the request B finish before the request A, then the value is changed in the incorrect order.

So instead of using

`this.movies.push(...)`

and

`id: this.myId`

, please use

```
this.movies[index] = ...
```

and

```
id: this.idStr[index]
```

Hope this help